# iPhone How to clip crescent moon pattern

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, draw, ellipse, clip

With help from stack overflow i am getting familiar with quartz drawing in iPhone. I want to make code that clips crescent moon pattern, this what i have so far, but its not working quite as i expect:

```
contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(contextRef);
onlyDrawTopHalf = YES;
halfMultiplier = onlyDrawTopHalf ? -1.0 : 1.0;
ellipse = CGRectMake(50, 50, 128, 128);
clipRect = CGRectOffset(ellipse, halfMultiplier * ellipse.size.width / 2, 0);
CGContextClipToRect(contextRef, clipRect);
CGContextRestoreGState(contextRef);


onlyDrawTopHalf = YES;
halfMultiplier = onlyDrawTopHalf ? -1.0 : 1.0;
ellipse = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 128);
clipRect = CGRectOffset(ellipse, halfMultiplier * ellipse.size.width / 2, 0);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(contextRef, clipRect);
CGContextEOClip(contextRef);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, ellipse);
```

To be precise, first paragraph of code draws circle (this works), second one should clip ellipse from it, but this is not working as intended.

Comment: try setting the clipping first before drawing the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Both shapes need to be perfect circles, not ellipses. Second circles' radius should be a little smaller and it should be a little bir shifted to the right (or left) to get the perfect crescent effect.

Comment: They have same staring points (50, 50), but radii are different (100, 128) and (128, 128).

Comment: Then you should slide the stating points a little bit. and use the perfect circle shape instead of ellipse. (100, 100) instead of (128, 128) for example.

Comment: I don't need perfect circles. I want to draw a circle, and than clip ellipse shaped area from it. First paragraph draws circle (that works), second should clip ellipse from it, but it's not working as expected. How can i solve this?